# http://localhost:5000/user/signup 404 not found

Tags: python, flask

So I'm trying to set up a simple registration application where users sign up and login however the code doesn't seem to be finding the user/signup as 404 Not Found page appears.

**Here is the routes.py file**

```
from app import app
from user.models import User

@app.route('/user/signup', methods = ['POST'])
def signup():
  return User().signup()
```

**And here is the app.py file**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

# Routes
from user import routes

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')


@app.route('/dashboard/')
def dashboard():
    return render_template('dashboard.html')
    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

**This is what I'm trying to pass to user/signup which is models.py**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

class User:

    def signup(self):

        user = {
            "_id": "",
            "name": "",
            "email": "",
            "password": ""
        }

        return jsonify(user), 200
```

Home.html and Dashboard.html are both loaded however when trying to go to http://localhost:5000/user/signup i receive a not found 404 page and this is displayed in my VS Code:

127.0.0.1 - - [09/Dec/2020 16:07:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Answer (score 0):

You can use Blueprints for this purpose. Blueprints help in logically organising your flask app into several parts.
The following implementation should work.

**routes.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint
from user.models import User

_user = Blueprint('user', __name__)

@_user.route('/user/signup', methods = ['POST'])
def signup():
  return User().signup()
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

# Routes
from user import routes

app.register_blueprint(routes._user)
```

Comment: Hey yes that worked however now upon signing up it brings me to http://localhost:5000/dashboard for some reason, do you know why that might be?

@EDIT

Oh nevermind, for some reason the script.js hasn't updated on the chrome localhost even when it was saved in VS Code. Strange.

Comment: It might have been cached by the browser.

Comment: Do you know why I might be getting this error: AttributeError: partially initialized module 'user.routes' has no attribute '_user' (most likely due to a circular import)
Traceback (most recent call last):     ?

I'm trying to to connect it to MondoDB

Comment: In this case, I think it is due to importing app in routes.py and then importing routes in app.py